# Isometries of $(\mathbb{R},\min\{|\cdot|,1\})$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have the following question:

> Let $d_1(x,y)=|x-y|$ and $d_2(x,y)=\min\{|x-y|,1\}$ be metrics on $\mathbb{R}$. Are bijective isometries of $(\mathbb{R},d_2)$ the same bijective isometries of $(\mathbb{R},d_1)$?

Clearly every isometry of $(\mathbb{R},d_1)$ is an isometry on $(\mathbb{R},d_2)$. I think they aren't equal. Does anyone know an example of an isometry of $(\mathbb{R},d_2)$ that is not isometry of $(\mathbb{R},d_1)$?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bijective isometry $f$ of $\langle\Bbb R,d_2\rangle$ is going to have to take each interval $[n,n+1]$ with $n\in\Bbb Z$ to an interval $[x_n,x_n+1]$ for some $x_n\in\Bbb R$ in one of two ways: either $f(\xi)=\xi+x_n-n$ for each $\xi\in[n,n+1]$, or $f(\xi)=x_n+1-(\xi-n)=x_n+1+n-\xi$. In other words, $f\upharpoonright[n,n+1]$ is a linear map of slope $1$ or $-1$.

Suppose that $f(\xi)=\xi+x_n-n$. Then $f(n+1)=x_n+1$, and $f$ must map $[n+1,n+2]$ onto $[x_n+1,x_n+2]$, not onto $[x_n,x_n+1]$. An easy proof by induction shows that $f(n+k)=x_n+k$ for each $k\in\Bbb Z^+$. A similar argument working to the left shows that $f(n+k)=x_n+k$ for all $k\in\Bbb Z$, so that $f$ is simply a right translation of $\Bbb R$ by $x_n-n$.

I leave it to you to check that the other case is similar: in that case $f$ is a reflection followed by a translation. Thus, you get the same isometries as with the usual metric.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understood the first case, I'm going to try the second one. A little dumb question: translations and reflections and compositions of these are all of the (bijective) isometries of $\mathbb{R}$, right?

Comment: @JonSK: You're welcome. Yes, any composition of these fellows is either a translation, or multiplication by $-1$ followed by a translation.